# How to get the total number of results on Drupal with JSON:API?

Tags: drupal, json-api

I need to get the total number of results when using JSON:API with Drupal.

Apparently that's been introduced in Drupal 9.3 as described on this page:
https://www.drupal.org/node/3246951

However the page doesn't explain how to actually do it. It says that the number of results is now in the `meta` object, but if I call `/jsonapi/node/some_node_type`, there is no `count` property in `meta`.

Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Comment: Looks to me like you need to create a module that has an event subscriber that subscribes to `ResourceTypeBuildEvents::BUILD` and then calls `$event->setCollectionSizeMemberName('count')`. I am just going by what's written in the change record though, I have not tried.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It looks like `setCollectionSizeMemberName` has not been implemented. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21jsonapi%21src%21ResourceType%21ResourceTypeBuildEvent.php/class/ResourceTypeBuildEvent/9.4.x.x

Comment: Oh, I see they are "Draft" change records... that's a shame